Limit rsync resource usage
I run a server mostly for off-site backup purposes for my job. But since I have a server, I do run a few applications in it.
The machine is an older Intel i7 with 16gb memory running Ubuntu Server.
One of the tasks I have automates there (via Cron) is a simple rsync the make some of the files available for another application.
rsync -ahvrO --delete --exclude={'Capture','Trash','Selects','.BridgeSort','*.csv','*.txt'} /samba/A4/files/ /redpool/A4/

It runs once a day and usually it does not take to much processing. But when I'm in the middle of a big job, the number of files per day grow a lot and it takes a lot of resources making all the other application become very slow or stop working.
This bottleneck is in the filesystem, I run a ZFS Pool in regular mechanical hard drives. I won't change the structure of the filesystem for now, but I would like to try and limit the amount of resources it takes, but in a "cronifiable" way. It's a lower priority task, so it could take longer and it would not be a huge problem I just want it to not take up all the resources available.

Ciao Augusto, welcome on SuperUser. What about nice -n 19 whatever? ( rsync....). PS> Give it a look here too. (--bwlimit=RATE  to limit bandwidth nice to limit cpu).

Usually with nice you should solve this problem. Read man nice:

nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority

You can limit resources via

You can limit the resources (CPU) via nice...
nice -n 19 rsync -ahvrO --delete --exclude={'Capture','Trash','Selects','.BridgeSort','*.csv','*.txt'} /samba/A4/files/ /redpool/A4/


In rsync you can limit if needed bandwidth with the explicit option --bwlimit=RATE

In rsync you can limit memory with --max-alloc=SIZE.


But really nice should be enough.

Cool, I didn't know rsync could limit the bandwidth too. I'll take a look at both nice and limiting options in rsync. Thanks a lot, this certainly will solve my issue.
